# duvida com json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

tenho um json, no meu formulario tenho um botao "Proximo" e "Anterior", eu preciso criar um codigo que mostre o proximo ou o resgistro anterior, conforme clica nos botoes, estou usando angular, alguem poderia dar uma dica de como poderia ser esse codigo ?

json

```
[{
    "Type": "Debito",
    "Date": "01/11/2016",
    "TransactionValue": 371.6,
    "Id": "388354",
    "Description": "ENVIO TEV",
    "Checksum": 388354,
    "lancado": "Não"
}, {
    "Type": "Debito",
    "Date": "01/11/2016",
    "TransactionValue": 148.0,
    "Id": "389749",
    "Description": "ENVIO TEV",
    "Checksum": 389749,
    "lancado": "Não"
}, {
    "Type": "Debito",
    "Date": "04/11 /2016 ",
    "TransactionValue ": 508.2,
    "Id ": "33531 ",
    "Description ": "PAG BOLETO ",
    "Checksum ": "33531",
    "lancado ": "Não "
}]
```

nao consegui ajustar o json aki, aki tem uma imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tem algum código pronto ?

Comment: Como é esse json? Posta ai esse json e o código que você ja tem

Comment: fiz um ng-prepeat cria varias divs, quando clico numa div, ele abre uma tela com os dados do registro, nessa mesma tela, quero criar um botao avancar e voltar, pra nao ter q fechar a tela e clicar em outra div

Comment: Cara, se você usar rotas você pode usar um Angular Breadcrumb que é bem maneiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No controller vc seta o `atual = 0`

Supondo que sua lista esta numa variavel chamada `registros`

```
<div class="local_exibicao_dados">{{registros[atual]}}</div>


<a ng-click="atual--" ng-show="atual > 0">Anterior</a>
{{atual}}
<a ng-click="atual++" ng-show="atual < registros.length">Próximo</a>
```